# Can I play Ticket to Ride on my iPad against people using Ticket to Ride pocket?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, online

I want to play against my friends on Ticket to Ride but I wondering if I can if they are on their iPhones and I am on my iPad?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all iOS versions of TTR may be involved in a multiplayer game, but only with expansions that are available on all devices.

Comment: I believe you are incorrect about expansions, at least for Local multiplayer. I have TTR on my iPad with all expansions purchased. On my phone running Android with only the base TTR game and no expansions, I am able to join games created on my iPad for expansion maps. So I think only the creator of the Local game has to have the expansions. Anyone joining an Online local game would have to have the expansions to play them, though.

Comment: Interesting. I think that they may have changed that - I wrote my answer a couple of years ago, and I remember hearing that there was a big update to the app that changed lots of things, especially ones relating to expansions. Or maybe I was wrong two years ago, it's hard to say.

Comment: I think you're right - I know as of this past December it was opened up, because my extended family played several games with several expansions that only I had purchased on the one device. But it does seem like that wasn't always the case.

Answer (score 0):

As [official site](https://www.daysofwonder.com/online/en/t2r) says, you may:

> - Online Play (WiFi or 3G) against other iPad, Android, Mac and PC gamers with Days of Wonder Online support
> - Players can challenge rail barons playing on other platforms including Steam PC and Mac, Android, iPad, and on Days of Wonder's online portal

They did not say exactly about iPhones, but I think they did not make special version for iPhones only.